# Why does my Eps file look like an image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-format, clipping-mask, eps

Why my eps (eps 10) file in Adobe AI is not working and it behaves like an image? I can't change anything. When I look at the layer panel it seems like an image.I deleted the layer of the link file. There was no link picture, I saved it in eps10 after seeing that everything is fine. But the next day I see that the file is not working anymore.
someone can tell why this is so, then I will not make the same mistake.

I have 3 files in the same condition. All of the files were clipping mask.

Comment: This is unanswerable as it stands. There's no information about the file structure at all. The files may*actually* be nothing more than embedded raster images. EPS does *not* mean something *must* be vector. EPS is merely a file wrapper.

Comment: An EPS file can be an image. In fact there is no restriction that vector drawings can bot have raster images. But make sure its not linked but rather embedded in illustrator.

Comment: I deleted the layer of the link file. There was no link picture, I saved it in eps10 after seeing that everything is fine. But the next day I see that the file is not working anymore.
someone can tell why this is so, then I will not make the same mistake.

Comment: EPS can contain raster and vector elements.  There's no way to tell you much unless you are willing to share the EPS so that we can investigate it. Anything else can only be a guess.

Answer (score 4):

If you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> in Illustrator it goes into 'Outline Mode' and then, if all you can see at this point is a rectangle with a big `X` across, then your EPS file is a raster image (a photo), not actual vector shapes.

In which case, yes, making edits is *not* possible because there would be no actual shapes to edit in Illustrator. Illustrator does *not* make edits at the pixel level, that would be Photoshop instead.

[image]

Comment: @StevenPenny how would the computer know what your trying to do?